# How do I get Android Studio to build a debug version of my native library?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, cmake

I have converted a library from Visual Studio to Android Studio, and moved it from Visual Studio's solution file to a CMakeLists.txt file for CMake. So far, so good. The converted build system works, but as far as I can tell, it only builds a release version.

(When I set a breakpoint in the C++ code, it ignores it. When I set a breakpoint in the Java, the code stops correctly, but when I reach the C++ code, I just get assembly, not C++ source.)

What I need CMake to do is build a debug version of the library when I select that I want to run the program in debug mode in Android Studio, and to build a symbol-stripped version for release mode. I believe it's currently doing the latter (though it would be great if someone could confirm that), but I need to know how to coax it into doing the former as well.

There was a related question asked on StackOverflow, but that seemed to be about the inclusion of a release vs debug library rather than building one.

Here's the relevant portion of the CMakeLists.txt:

```
    set(ALL_FILES
            ${no_group_source_files}
            ${Header_Files__AppCommonsrc}
            ${Header_Files__commonsrc}
            ${Source_Files__AppCommonsrc}
            ${Source_Files__commonsrc}
    )

    add_library(
         NativeTools

         SHARED

         ${ALL_FILES} )

     find_library(
          log-lib

          log )

    set(MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS "-g2;-gdwarf-2;-O0;-fno-rtti;-fno-omit-frame-pointer;-mthumb;-fexceptions;-mfloat-abi=softfp;-fno-short-enums")
    set(MY_RELEASE_OPTIONS "-gline-tables-only;-O3;-fno-rtti;-fomit-frame-pointer;-fdata-sections;-mthumb;-fexceptions;-fno-short-enums")

    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${MY_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>")
    target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${MY_RELEASE_OPTIONS}>")

    if("${ANDROID_ABI}" STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
        set(ADDITIONAL_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES
                "../common/openssl/Android/openssl/libcrypto.a;"
                "../common/openssl/Android/openssl/libssl.a"
                )
    elseif("${ANDROID_ABI}" STREQUAL "arm64-v8a")
        set(ADDITIONAL_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES
                "../common/openssl/Android64/openssl/libcrypto.a;"
                "../common/openssl/Android64/openssl/libssl.a"
                )
    elseif("${ANDROID_ABI}" STREQUAL "x86_64")
        set(ADDITIONAL_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES
                "../common/openssl/Androidx64/openssl/libcrypto.a;"
                "../common/openssl/Androidx64/openssl/libssl.a"
                )
    elseif("${ANDROID_ABI}" STREQUAL "x86")
        set(ADDITIONAL_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES
                "../common/openssl/Androidx86/openssl/libcrypto.a;"
                "../common/openssl/Androidx86/openssl/libssl.a"
                )
    endif()
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "${ADDITIONAL_LIBRARY_DEPENDENCIES}" ${log-lib})
```